# Vagrant recipe compilation error

Tags: vagrant, cookbook, vagrant-provision

[Vagrant up issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfvCj.png)

I am trying to setting up vagrant, virtualbox to run ubuntu on virtual machine.
I am using following url since last one and half year but from last two week i am getting attached error. This error is related to entry.rb file. Please find attached image for more error information.

I am using following vagrant configuration file.

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.vm.box = "trusty64"
    config.vm.box_url = "http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/vagrant/trusty/current/trusty-server-cloudimg-amd64-vagrant-disk1.box"
    config.ssh.forward_agent = true
    config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.91.11"

    config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
        v.name = "unibox"
        v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "2048"]
        v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--cpuexecutioncap","90"]
        v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--cpus",1]
        # v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--nictype1", "virtio"]
        # v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--nictype2", "virtio"]
        # v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnshostresolver1", "on"]
        # v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnsproxy1", "off"]
        # v.auto_nat_dns_proxy = false
    end
    config.vm.provision "shell", path: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AOEpeople/chef-devbox/master/setup.sh"
end
```

Comment: For error image check first link on top of article "Vagrant up issue"

Comment: Prima facie, it looks that the action_class module is missing. can you please confirm chef client version.

Comment: Chef client version is 12.0.3

Comment: I have updated the chef client version to latest 12.19.36 and now when i run sudo ./provision.sh then i am getting different error related to default.rb. "Option name's value xxx does not match regular expression"

Comment: Please update the question with relevant errors with complete stacktrace. its difficult to apprehend your environment and settings.

Comment: Cookbook Trace:
---------------
  /etc/chef-devbox/cookbooks/devbox/recipes/instances.rb:40:in `block (2 levels) in from_file'
  /etc/chef-devbox/cookbooks/devbox/recipes/instances.rb:39:in `each'
  /etc/chef-devbox/cookbooks/devbox/recipes/instances.rb:39:in `block in from_file'
  /etc/chef-devbox/cookbooks/devbox/recipes/instances.rb:14:in `each'
  /etc/chef-devbox/cookbooks/devbox/recipes/instances.rb:14:in `from_file'
  /etc/chef-devbox/cookbooks/devbox/recipes/default.rb:28:in `from_file'

Comment: ================================================================================
Recipe Compile Error in /etc/chef-devbox/cookbooks/devbox/recipes/default.rb
================================================================================

Chef::Exceptions::ValidationFailed
----------------------------------
Option name's value demo does not match regular expression [/^([a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9]|_|-)[1,16]$/]

Comment: Something wrong with your recipe code.. With given information, hard to point out.. Please refer how to ask questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask